# Cannot import custom module in mac Pycharm "ImportError: No module named"

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, importerror

In Pycharm, I have the following folder tree:

```
|> Folder_1
|  > Folder_2
|     - file_1.py
|     - file_2.py
|     - __init__.py
```

I am trying to import file_2.py so that I can use it in file_1.py, but even typing: 
`import file_2`

in the python console results in the following error:

```
File "Traceback (most recent call last):
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
      File "<ipython-input-2-ac9ea41238ee>", line 1, in <module>
        import file_2.py
      File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
        module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
        module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
    ImportError: No module named 'file_2'
```

Then I tried making a new project from scratch, and it works fine.
So it is possible that a setting was changed in the current one that is is preventing custom modules to be imported.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To import a custom module (lets say a lib) you need to mark it as `Source` in pycharm. Let say i have a folder like this

```
lib/
    biopy.py
    ratata.py
```

Then i need to mark the lib folder (inside Pycharm) as `Source`. Right click it on the left side and:
`Mark dictionary as... --> Sources root`

After doing this i can do:

```
import biopy
import ratata
```

In any of my scripts in that project (you might also want to add the `lib` folder to your `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable).

EDIT: I have no idea about MAC having environment variables or not

Comment: Thanks Gabor, the directory is already set as root, the problem must be somewhere else..

Comment: Make sure that the imported files have different name from the script you want to run.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the difference between "script" and "imported files" here. I have defined both files as >>new python files, and named them  file_1 and file_2. The error comes when I type `import file_1` in the python console..

Answer (score 0):

For those who experience the same problem, this is what worked for me.

Disclaimer: this is non-sensical.

I typed `import file_1.py`. Got an error. Then I typed `import file_1` and it worked.

Don't necessarily expect this to work.